# Can not add backslash into input parameter using Python

Tags: python, string

I need to escape all special character and then add back slash () into input parameters using python. I have done something but it's not working. My code is below.

```
rname = request.POST.get('rname')
ename = re.escape(rname)
add_slash = ename + '\'
```

Here I need to escape all special character first and then add the `\` with that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backslash also needs to be escaped, like so

```
add_slash = ename + '\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Satya, **

## Your Solution

Try this below code,

```
rname = request.POST.get('rname')
ename = (re.escape(rname)) + "\\"
add_slash = ename
```

More knowledge about string literal so read below link,
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so c